# CS0117 - Xamarin not detecting 'Resources' folders and files

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have been developing a `Xamarin.Forms` app, initially on iOS and now for Android. 
I have run into a problem whereby my code is unable to see the resources being referenced in my `MainActivity.cs`.
I have the same error for two different resources.

I am following along with a Udemy course and the instructor is emphasising manually building some of the `xml` files, hence the two types, `axml` and `xml`.

First error

```
/Users/richardcurteis/Desktop/OneDrive/DevShared/XamarinProjects/NoteTaker/Droid/MainActivity.cs(35,35):
Error CS0117: `NoteTaker.Droid.Resource' does not contain a definition for `Menu' (CS0117) (NoteTaker.Droid)
```

Second error:

```
/Users/richardcurteis/Desktop/OneDrive/DevShared/XamarinProjects/NoteTaker/Droid/MainActivity.cs(21,21):
Error CS0117: `NoteTaker.Droid.Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for `action_add' (CS0117) (NoteTaker.Droid)
```

`MainActivity.cs`

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using SupportToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NoteTaker.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "Note Taker", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        int count = 1;

        private SupportToolbar toolbar;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Xamarin.Insights.Initialize (XamarinInsights.ApiKey, this);
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            new Database ();

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            toolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar> (Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar (toolbar);
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.addmenu, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
            case Resource.Id.action_add:
                Console.WriteLine ("Add button clicked");
                return true;

            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

`addmenu.xml` Which contains the `action_add` id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
      <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/addIcon"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

`Resources` tree

```
~/Desktop/OneDrive/DevShared/XamarinProjects/NoteTaker/Droid    
tree Resources/
Resources/
├── AboutResources.txt
├── Resource.designer.cs
├── drawable
│   └── addIcon.png
├── layout
│   ├── Main.axml
│   └── Toolbar.xml
├── menu
│   └── addmenu.xml
├── mipmap-hdpi
│   └── Icon.png
├── mipmap-mdpi
│   └── Icon.png
├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   └── Icon.png
├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   └── Icon.png
├── mipmap-xxxhdpi
│   └── Icon.png
└── values
    ├── Strings.xml
    └── styles.xml

9 directories, 13 files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what the issue was.
Previously when I had been coding I had initially placed the 'menu' folder in the wrong directory.
I had done this by right clicking accidentally 'layout' and clicking 'Add/New Folder'.

The problem came when I then manually dragged and dropped the folder into the correct place.
**But it seems that Xamarin only recognises files and folders that are added via the right click option** and the compiler then only saw the files in their original, incorrect location.

However simply deleting the files with right click/'Remove' **does not** solve the issue. 
Whilst the target file was removed from the Xamarin UI, it was not removed from the project directory on disk and as such a new file with the same name cannot be added.
I had to navigate to the project folder and run `rm -rf menu` to remove it.
Then go back to Xamarin and right click/Add/New Folder and New File.

Following that I cleaned the project and rebuilt and it worked like a charm.

This post on Xamarin forums tipped me off to what the issue was.

[Xamarin Post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41476/adding-image-files-to-android-resources-folder-not-showing-in-xamarin-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I created the folder and file with New Folder and New File.

My solution was to **Clean** the build and then **Build All**, before using Resource.Menu.
Aflter the build all, everything worked fine.

I think an alternative to this is to delete the "bin" and "obj" folder from your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

took me a while but i got it working this way:

If its a xamarin forms app, Change 
"Resource.Layout.Xxxx" => "Droid.Resource.Layout.Xxx"