# Visual Studio C# Xamarin - 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'menu'

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, resources

I am trying to test the Menus in my App, but when I add the folder `'menu'` with the XML file `'main.xml'`, I get the Error Below:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0117  'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'menu' MyMenus D:\User1\Apps\MyMenus\MyMenus\MainActivity.cs   24  Active
```

I have made sure the Build Setting is set to `Android Resource` for the XML file, and have tried to Cleaned and Rebuilt.
Whenever I rebuild, I get the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Toolbar) is an example about how to use Toolbar in Android, and you could see how to use `menu` in this example. Please make sure your usage is same with the example.

Comment: Check if the resource id has been generated in `Resource.designer.cs`. If it has not been generated, usually clean and rebuilding the project will generate it again , unless there is a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: It has not been generated, also when I clean and rebuild, i says the same error.

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message?

Comment: How did you add the `menu` folder ?  Right-click on the `Resource` folder in the Solution tree, Add->Add Files or dragged and dropped the `menu` folder into the `Resource` folder ? Which method is you used?

Comment: You could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258720/cs0117-xamarin-not-detecting-resources-folders-and-files